# How to understand dictionary results

Tags: grammar

When I search for a particular word in google or any other dictionary I will get multiple results like same word can be used as adjective and verb.
How to understand the results.

Please look at the image.
[image]

Comment: Yes, some words can have several meanings, or be used in several ways. Can you explain _what_ you find difficult to understand?

Comment: @oerkelens, my question is how 'worried' is used as adjective.given example-"your mother and I were very worried about you" here 'worried' is used as past participle only not as an adjective.

Comment: There is a clear example in your result: _Your mother and I were worried about you_. Another example could be _The worried mother called the police about her son's disappearance_. It's used pretty much the same way as other adjectives. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @JNRaju Participles can be used as adjectives. The past participle *worried* is used as an adjective in  *your mother and I were very worried*. One way to be sure of this is because [the word *very* can modify  participles used as adjectives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114402/use-of-very-to-modify-verb-participles-used-as-adjectives-correct-or-not-and).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are looking a word up in the dictionary, a good way to eliminate definitions you don't need is to know the part of speech of the word.  For example, if in the text you are reading, *worry* is being used as a verb, then you want the verb definition from the dictionary.

  - If you are having problems determing the part of speech, keep in mind English relies on word order - Subject [noun] - Verb [verb] - Auxillary [adverb] - Object [noun].
  - It will help to know very well your articles and other determiners (nouns always follow those), pronouns (meaning the "slot" of subject or object is "taken"), conjunctions and prepositions.
  - Know common word endings, e.g. *-ed* is usually a past participle or past tense form of a verb, *-y* ends a lot of adjectives, *-ly* ends a lot of verbs, *-ation*/*-tion* words are usually nouns, etc.
- Most dictionaries also place the most common meanings first.
- You may just need to "brute force" it and try each meaning out in your sentence until you come across one that works.